# How do I preserve a change locally without committing it?

Tags: git, gitattributes

Occasionally, I need to add a modification to my local copy of a git branch that I don't want to commit, such as a workaround for my computer that shouldn't be included in my team's repo. What I would like to do is, in effect, gitignore *part* of a committed file. There seem to be several possible methods:

1. Add the change in my local branch and revert it before pushing. This method is simple, but not automated.
2. Ensure that when the site builds, files are piped through a script that patches in the change.  This method is simple and automated but I haven't yet looked into how to accomplish it.
3. Use `.git/info/attributes` and filters to automatically patch in the change when I run `git checkout` and automatically remove it when I run `git add`. This method is automated but not simple: it makes my working tree always have uncommitted changes, which is frustrating.
4. Use my modification only if an environment variable is set. This method would clutter the team's repo.

Is there another method, or a better way of using these methods?

Comment: Stash your local change?

Comment: But seriously if this happens always for some config file then this entire file should be git ignored. Use a nonignored file to generate the canonical config file and ignore it.

Comment: I suppose I could commit the change, then delete it, and `git stash` the deletion, which would restore the change. Then I can `git stash apply` before pushing, which would re-delete the change. That might be interesting to explore, but it seems just as complicated as method 1.

The change is just to part of a file, so `.gitignore` won't help, I don't think.

Comment: [The Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files) outlines that there's no really easy way to do this.  The best way is to have some sort of way to override or use untracked config files if they're config files, but otherwise, there's no universal approach.

Comment: Is the file you wish to only partially commit, a config file, or is it some sort of compilable/executable code?

Comment: It's code that gets compiled.

Comment: What about just using `git add -p` and add the wanted change to your commit ?

Comment: @Ôrel, that's not a bad idea, though it has a small inconvenience, similar to method 3: I will always have unstaged changes in my working tree. I'm in the habit of making sure I don't have any unstaged changes for long.

Comment: about cluttering the team's repo: do other developpers have similar local hacks ? if some do, it's probably better to have a referenced, unified way to do it ...

Comment: Depending on how much effort you want to put into this, I prefer one of the two suggestions by @matt. Stashing is not optimal, as you mentioned, but it is very easy and works out of the box with almost no effort. For me, it is usually good enough. You can also add the file to `.gitignore` after you pushed the "server" version.